# What are some good sources for Old Marathi and Old Konkani as would have been spoken around 1100-1600?

Tags: historical-linguistics, resource-request, sanskrit, indo-aryan

I get that this will be a very difficult question, perhaps one with no easily accessible answer as vernacular MIA/NIA speech was not often written down and even if so, it was meant to resemble OIA in a mimicking fashion. But if there are any good sources, please do make them known to me.

Comment: How can how something was spoken hundreds of years ago be known? It cannot. Only written forms exist from that many years ago...

Comment: @Lambie I should have phrased it better. I just generally meant like sources that tell me how the language was (literary form or otherwise) at that time

Answer (score 1):

Tulpule & Feldhaus (1999) *A dictionary of Old Marathi* https://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/tulpule/

This source includes many usage examples. Marathi has the oldest literary record of the New Indo-Aryan languages, and started vernacularizing literary vocabulary at an early stage.